# PHP: Filling in the 'gaps' in an array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've got a php array (obtained through checkbox values in a form - as you know checkboxes only show up in the _POST variable when they are not set).

```
Array
(
    [2] => 0,2
    [3] => 0,3
)
```

I need a way to 'fill in' the gaps between the range 0-5. So above would look like (filling the empty spaces with '-1'. I tried `array_merge()` with an array filled with '-1' but that didn't work.

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => -1
    [2] => 0,2
    [3] => 0,3
    [4] => -1
    [5] => -1
)
```

I think I may have gone down the wrong road with the problem I am trying to solve, but I have put too much time into this solution to back out - a feeling I am sure most of you are familiar with(!)

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

array_merge doesn't work, but '+' does!

```
$a = array(2 => 22, 3 => 33);
$b = $a + array_fill(0, 6, -1);
```

the key order is wrong though, so you might want to `ksort` it.

Comment: Thanks stereofrog, I went with this in the end (code below for anyone doing something similar with _POST. Just for future reference, does anyone know which is most processor friendly between this and the above foreach?

Comment: theoretically, the loop should be faster, but negligibly so

Comment: @aboved you shouldn't care of processor with such a case. 5 or even 100 iterations wouldn't make processor too much work. though you don't need this loop at all.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do it in a loop?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    if (!isset($array[$i]))
    {
        $array[$i] = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you array is variable length you would want to use:

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($array); $i++)
    {
        if (!isset($array[$i]))
        {
            $array[$i] = -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This wouldn't feed the OPs needs. In his example the array has to values but he wants to fill it with **5** values. With your code, only the first two elements would be set.

Comment: Actually I dont think this would work in your case. But it may be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

With strong inspiration from [user187291](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556921/21995934), you could use [array_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) instead of array_fill() to get to correct order without using ksort or loops:

```
$a = array_fill(0, 6, -1); // creates a "dummy"-array
$b = array_replace($a, array(2 => 22, 3 => 33)); // replaces the keys in the temporary dummy-array
```

Comment: For curious readers: [array_replace() vs. union operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537384/2943403)