# array_replace() vs. union operator in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merging-data

In PHP, (*given that `$a`, `$b` and `$c` are arrays*) is `$a = array_replace($b, $c)` always functionally identical to `$a = $c + $b`?

I can't seem to find any edge cases that would indicate otherwise.

(*just working with one dimension, this question isn't concerned with recursion, ie: `array_replace_recursive()`*)

---

**Edit**: I found a note in a comment that suggests that the union operator will preserve references, but I haven't noticed `array_replace()` failing to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*EDIT*: Ah sorry, I didn't notice the arguments were reversed. The answer is yes, then, because the resulting array always has the two arrays merged, but while `+` gives priority to values in the first array and `array_replace` to the second.

The only actual difference would be in terms of performance, where `+` *may* be preferable because when it finds duplicates it doesn't replace the value; it just moves on. Plus, it doesn't entail a (relatively expensive) function call.

---

No. `array_replace` replaces elements, while `+` considers the first value:

```
<?php
print_r(array_replace([0 => 1], [0 => 2]));
print_r([0 => 1] + [0 => 2]);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

To [cite](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) the manual:

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

As for references, they are preserved in both cases.

Comment: Spectacular, thanks @Artefacto -- I figured they were, though I was concerned of some undocumented edge cases (*as I've noticed PHP is somewhat notorious for*)

Comment: I've found a nice image and description explain full difference: https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/

Answer (score 6):

It should also be mentioned that array_merge also functions the same as array_replace *if the supplied arrays have non-numeric keys*.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer to the question :)